# function returning none value

Tags: python, nonetype

Why is my function returning null value?
My code takes 2 inputs `a` and `b` and gives the common smallest prime number and if it does not have any common smallest prime number then it will return `-1` 
example 
input  `3`, `6`
output `3`
input `3`, `7`
output `-1`

```
def checkprime(ans,i):
    if (ans <= 2): 
        if(ans == 2):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if (ans % i == 0): 
        return False
    if (i * i > ans): 
        return True 
    return checkprime(ans, i + 1) 

def commomdivisor(a,b,ans):

    if ((a*b)+1<ans):
        return -1
    if(a%ans==0 and b%ans==0):
        i=2
        if(checkprime(ans,i)== True):

            print("type",type(ans))
            fans=ans
            return int(fans)
        else:
            commomdivisor(a,b,ans+1)
    else :
        commomdivisor(a,b,ans+1)


a,b= map(int, input().split())
#b=int(input())
ans=2
print("type",type(ans))
print(commomdivisor(a,b,ans))
```

Comment: Python functions return `None` if nothing is explicitly returned. In your `else` closures, you are just calling the functions but not returning what you get from them. So add `return` before `commomdivisor` calls.

Comment: Function is returning `None` because you didn't put `return` statement in `else` in `commomdivisor` function.

Comment: There are a couple of (logic) paths in `commomdivisor` that do not have a return statement.